# What's the true story about Galilei?

Tags: galileo

Scientists use the story of Galilei to advocate the glory of the sciences and the stupidity of the church. This is obvious from ironic remarks made by them that criticize its attitude. In fact, this is exactly the same attitude to the church as the church had towards the science of the heavens (that is, the heliocentric view). The difference being though that the church was rational in it's attitude. So they were not *exactly* the same.

Gallilei is idolized and given the status of a hero. The hero of science who dared to fight against the irrational views of the church in the name of Reason and Enlightment.

But what is true of all the stories? Was he thrown in jail? Ot maybe something worse? Did he believe in God himself?

Incidentally, Galileo Galilei is called Galilei in Holland. I don't know about other countries but it could be they call him Galileo there.

Comment: [Very huge Bibliography available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Galilei). At least [Drake (1978)](https://archive.org/details/galileoatwork00stil), [Heilbron (2010)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Galileo/tnIVDAAAQBAJ), [Finocchiaro (1989)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Galileo_Affair/k7D1CXFBl2gC)

Comment: @Deschele Schilder   Your questionis flawed.  You write "the chruch", as if there has been only one demonination of Christanity, with only one chruch organization, in all of history.  But there have been and still are dozens, if not hundreds, of other Christian denominations, Protestant, Eastern Orthodox, Oriental, etc., etc. totally separate from the Roman Catholic Church and often bitterly opposed to it.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Yes. And the heliocentric view was allowed. Only its publication for the masses. The pseudo science of Galilei was allowed. Just as Galileo allowed the geocentric view, though I doubt what Galileo would have done if *he* had the power.

Comment: Re, "...called Galilei in Holland." But that's not what he called himself! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Galilei#Name

Comment: @M.A.Golding, Yes, there are many denominations of Christianity, but Galileo was only prosecuted for, and convicted of heresy by one of those.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Then all streetnames should be changed here!

Answer (score 6):

As Mauro Allegranza mentioned, the literature is enormous. To put it short, Galileo was censored. He was given a warning not to advocate Copernican theory as an established fact but was permitted to discuss it as a mathematical hypothesis. (The main reason was that the Bible contains a sentence which seems to imply that Sun rotates around the Earth. Galileo dared to propose his own interpretation of this sentence. But interpretation of the Bible was strictly the prerogative of the Church.)

He violated this warning, and published a book for a broad audience, where some passages could be interpreted as a ridicule of the arguments stated by the Pope himself.

Then he was summoned to Rome, and forced to abdicate his views (under the threat of torture, and worse). He publicly abdicated, and after that was kept under some kind of home arrest.
He lived with a friend, and was prohibited to travel or to publish anything on the topic. Copernicus book was banned. Notice that it was banned 74 years after publication, and only in connection with Galileo's process.

One can add, that a) Galileo's main argument "proving" revolution of the Earth was wrong (it was based on his incorrect explanation of tides), and that at that time there was no conclusive experiment which should allow to prove or disprove it. b) He was in priority conflict with some Jesuit scientists who could possibly cause his persecution, and c) There were many scientists
at that time who shared the heliocentric views, and had good relations with the church establishment. So some researchers argue that he simply provoked the Church to ban Copernicus theory. On this I can cite two sources which are critical with respect to Galileo:

A. Koestler, The sleepwalkers, and

S. Gindikin, Tales of mathematicians and physicists.

Their point of view is that Galileo unnecessarily provoked the Church.
They unfavorably compare him with his contemporary Kepler who never had any conflict with Church. (It is true that Kepler was a Protestant, but Protestants also have a record of burning heretics).

And to answer the last question: yes Galileo believed in God, and was a devote Catholic.

Comment: So would have provoked the church to ban his own theory? Or was his view that the earth was in the middle of it all?

Comment: His view was that Sun is in the center, and the Earth rotates about the Sun. And of course he did not provoke the Church intentionally. He was just promoting what he thought was true.

Comment: So it was only because of the publication of his book? Was it not certain at that time yet that the earth rotates around the sun?

Comment: No, it was not certain. The conclusive experimental proofs only appeared in 19th century; of course by that time no one doubted the Earth rotation and revolution.

Comment: The book was an occasion. People who convicted him before the pope were probably his scientific opponents with whom he had priority disputes.

Comment: What are priority disputes?

Comment: One was about the discovery of Jupiter satellites. You can read the details in Drake's book mentioned by Mauro Allegranza.

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko  Kepler was a Protestant, and Protestants were often burned as heretics by the Catholics.  In 1600 Kepler was banished from Graz because he refused to convert to Catholicism.

Comment: @M.A.Golding: Protestants were also burned by Protestants (M. Servetus, for example).

Comment: So it was not considered irrational to believe in science as well as in God?

Comment: Why was the book of Copernicus banned after such a long time? Was the church afraid for resparked interest? Was Galileo a well-known figure?

Comment: No. Many Catholic priests and Jesuits made important contributions to sciences. Copernicus himself was a canon at a church in Frauenburg.

Comment: You can easily find answers to this sort of questions on Internet, starting with Wikipedia. This site policies discourage long discussions in the comments.